# How to design a generic method to avoid code repetition in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have several methods (around 10) in my Java code that have similar structure, but different return types, method arguments, and the specific methods they call (`someMethod()`). An example is:

```
private int f1(int t) {
    AtomicReference<Integer> res = new AtomicReference<>();
    res.set(someMethod1(t));
    // ...
    return res.get();
}

private int f2(String text) {
    AtomicReference<Integer> res = new AtomicReference<>();
    res.set(someMethod2(text));
    // ...
    return res.get();
}

private float f3(float x, float y) {
    AtomicReference<Float> res = new AtomicReference<>();
    res.set(someMethod3(x, y));
    // ...
    return res.get();
}

private float f4() {
    AtomicReference<Float> res = new AtomicReference<>();
    res.set(someMethod4());
    // ...
    return res.get();
}
```

I would like to avoid code repetition and design a generic helper method that can handle these cases. What would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: Are you using the method parameters in anywhere else, other than to call `someMethodN()`?

Comment: What’s the use of the `AtomicReference` in these methods?

Comment: What does `// …` stand for in these methods? Is it the same for all of them or different in each?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, only used in `someMethodN()`

Comment: @TimMoore Yes same code for all

Comment: @TimMoore The purpose of the method is to send a message to another thread and then wait for a response. The complexity of this process is intentionally hidden, and only the variable is shown because it has the same type as the return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a generic helper like this:

```
private <T> T helper(Supplier<T> method) {
    AtomicReference<T> res = new AtomicReference<>();
    res.set(method.get());
    // ...
    return res.get();
}
```

It takes a `Supplier<T>`, representing the method you are going to call. The arguments to the method will be captured on the caller's side.

For example, `f1` can be declared using this `helper` like this:

```
private int f1(int t) {
    return helper(() -> someMethod1(t));
}
```

Another example for `f3`,

```
private float f1(float x, float y) {
    return helper(() -> someMethod3(x, y));
}
```

Comment: The `AtomicReference` can also be directly initialized as `var res = new AtomicReference<>(method.get());`.